# Semaphore values in c

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

If I understand correctly, from this post:
http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html

Then after each thread passes from sem_wait(&sem1) because of an sem_post(&sem1) from somewhere else, the value of the semaphore should increment.
So if I do:

```
    sem_wait(&sem1);
    int sval2;
    if (sem_getvalue(&sem1, &sval2) == 0){
        printf("Semaphore value: %d\n", sval2);
    }
```

With

```
sem_init(&sem1, 0, 0);
```

Executed previously, my output should be:

```
1
2
3
4
etc......
```

I am asking this, because in my project, the events seem to be following the correct order, but when I do the sem_getvalue, the output on some semaphores stay constant (0), at others goes +1 once, then stays constant (1), and on others it goes up and down (1, then 3, then 4, then 5, then 3, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

`sem_post` increases the value of a semaphore by one. `sem_wait` decrements a semaphore's value (decreases it by one), provided that won't make it go below zero (otherwise it blocks). (See `man sem_wait` for more technical details.)

The values you are seeing are due to the order that `sem_wait` and `sem_post` are being called.

Answer (score 1):

`sem_post` increments, `sem_wait` decrements (and blocks until the semaphore has a positive value, so as not to decrement it below zero). The values you observe with `sem_getvalue` will depend on the order that the threads run and the order of the various increments and decrements.

Comment: Oh ok, I missed the part of decrementing, my perception was that it waits until the value of the semaphore is equal to the value sem_wait gets (based on the order it is called).
Thanks